# Making an address book application using JAVA

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, 3-tier, client-server

I am a Java beginner and am going to make a small address book client program using java swing.

And my goal is implementing 3-tier architecture. (No sql queries are in client program)

What would be the best approach for this?

I thought (Java EE)--(XML or JSON)--(MySQL) would be the one, but isn't it too hard for beginner? :)

What else could be?

Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: You told that you want to make small address book using java swing. After that you told that JavaEE would be one choice. Obviously it is contradictory, because Swing is not JavaEE. Swing is JavaSE. JavaEE is for web.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by Java EE (J2EE is 1999 vintage terminology - drop the "2", please.)

You can write a web-based address book using servlets and JSPs.  If you want a relational database you can use JDBC, but it's possible to make do without that.

You should make your data access layer interface-based.  That will let you change the implementation without affecting clients.

Your UI will be JSPs.  You'll have a front controller servlet that will accept requests, figure out how to handle them, and send the response to the next view.

Answer (score 1):

**Java EE** contains many technologies that can make building this type of application easier:

- **EJB** - Use a session bean to create your application.
- **JAX-RS**  - Expose your session bean as a RESTful service via XML and JSON messsages.
- **JAXB** - Handles the conversion of your model objects to/from XML and JSON
- **JPA** - Handles storing your model objects in the database without you writing JDBC code

If this sounds like a lot, look at how little code you need to write:

```
package org.example;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="CustomerService",
                        type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void create(Customer customer) {
        entityManager.persist(customer);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("{id}")
    public Customer read(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        return entityManager.find(Customer.class, id);
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void update(Customer customer) {
        entityManager.merge(customer);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void delete(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        Customer customer = read(id);
        if(null != customer) {
            entityManager.remove(customer);
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("findCustomersByCity/{city}")
    public List<Customer> findCustomersByCity(@PathParam("city") String city) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findCustomersByCity");
        query.setParameter("city", city);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

**For a Full Example**

- [Part 1 - The Database](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html)
- [Part 2 - Mapping the Database to JPA Entities](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-25.html)
- [Part 3 - Mapping JPA entities to XML (using JAXB)](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html)
- [Part 4 - The RESTful Service](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html)
- [Part 5 - The Client](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html)

Answer (score 0):

You say you are a Java beginner, the answer to your dilemma IMO depends on your experience with other languages (and programming in general). There are alot of layers in a web application, meaning many things can go wrong, so I think it is best to start with the easy stuff and work your way up.  SO... I would recommend not getting carried away with XML, JSON, MVC, etc  on your first app. You can still write a great application and learn alot of stuff by keeping it a little lower tech, such as using JSP pages that use JavaBeans and letting the beans handle the SQL, etc.

You can (and should) move on from there with AJAX, MVC architectures, etc.